# Memory leak, misuse of thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, memory

Im trying to use the threads for the first time, but cant tell why am i getting memory leak, cause of misuse of the thread, or cause im that stupid and forgot to free something, but at this point, i cant tell, which one (or both) is it.

This is the procedure that is being called on click

```
procedure TmainForm.scrollFrameClick(item:TEquipmentItem; itemFrame:TitemFrame);
begin
item.fullImage:=itemFrame.itemImage.Picture.Graphic;
setCurrentSearchItem(item);
end;
```

Procedure that calling thread

```
procedure TmainForm.setCurrentSearchItem(item:TEquipmentItem);
begin

if not(assigned(searchResultTable)) then
  searchResultTable:=TItemHtmlTable.Create
else
  begin
    freeandnil(searchResultTable);
    searchResultTable:=TItemHtmlTable.Create;
  end;

if getDomTh<>nil then
  if getDomTh.Finished then
    begin
      getDomTh.Terminate;
      getDomTh.WaitFor;
      FreeAndNil(getDomTh);
    end
  else
    begin
      getDomTh.WaitFor;
      getDomTh.Terminate;
      FreeAndNil(getDomTh);
    end;

getDomTh:=TCreateDomThread.Create(false,'http://www.example.com/ru/items/'+inttostr(item.ID),searchResultTable.DomTree);

currentItemImage.Picture.Graphic:=item.fullImage;
itemNameLab.Caption:=item.ItemName;
itemTypeLab.Caption:=item.ItemTypeName;
itemSubtypeLab.Caption:=item.ItemSubtypeName;

/////////////////
// At this point i would call a thread and use the result from the "searchResultTable"
/////////////////

if getDomTh<>nil then
  if getDomTh.Finished then
    freeandnil(searchResultTable)
  else
    begin
      getDomTh.WaitFor;
      getDomTh.Terminate;
      FreeAndNil(getDomTh);
      freeandnil(searchResultTable);
    end;
end;
```

This is the thread unit

```
unit threadUnit;

interface

uses System.Classes,System.SysUtils, parser;

type
  TCreateDomThread = class(TThread)
  private
    pDomTree:TDomTree;
    pUrl:string;
  public
    property tDomTree:TDomTree read pDomTree write pDomTree;
    property tUrl:string read pUrl write pUrl;
    constructor Create(suspended:boolean; Url:string; DomTree:TDomTree);
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

uses main;


constructor TCreateDomThread.Create(suspended:boolean; Url:string; DomTree:TDomTree);
begin
  tDomTree:=DomTree;
  tUrl:=Url;
  inherited Create(suspended);
end;

procedure TCreateDomThread.Execute;
begin
    if Terminated then Exit;
    mainForm.getDomTree(tUrl, tDomTree);
end;
end.
```

DomTree retrieval

```
 procedure TmainForm.getDomTree(url:string; outputDomTree:TDomTree);
    var
      HtmlTxt: string;
    begin
      try
        HtmlTxt := IdHTTP1.Get(url);
        if not outputDomTree.RootNode.RunParse(HtmlTxt) then
          TThread.Queue(nil,procedure begin showmessage('Can'#39'tParse HTML!') end);
      except
        on E: Exception do
          TThread.Queue(nil,procedure begin ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ' : ' + E.Message); end);
      end;
    end;
```

If you call for the click a couple of times, taskmanager shows that committed memory is always increasing.
I had no luck with debugging that, any advise would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

So there is a bunch of `TDomTree` which are not being free, but i couldnt understand, from where, cause thread is destroyed as expected

[Delphi memory manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYqB0.jpg)

EDIT 2:
Found the error.

Comment: What evidence do you have of a memory leak?  (Don't rely on what you think TaskMan might be telling you.)

Comment: Well since i can click 50 times and use 100+ mb of ram, i thought, that i could call it a leak

Comment: Not related to the memory leak, but the first seven lines of `setCurrentSearchItem` can be replaced by the two lines in the `else` branch alone. It is perfectly safe to do `X.Free` (and therefore `FreeAndNil(X)`) if `X` is `nil`. That's because `X.Free` basically does `if Assigned(X) then X.Destroy`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that

Comment: Instead of TaskMan, see what results you get from setting Delphi's memory manager to FullDebugMode.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: thats what i did, and it is compiling.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Actually, that is allowed, but it is bad practice.

Comment: Another hint: `'Can'#39'tParse HTML!'` can also be written `'Can''t parse HTML!'` (+typo fixed), which I find easier to read (and doesn't force me to remember Unicode codepoints). In a Pascal string literal, `''` means the `'` character.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand will do, thanks) also i changed the `tDomTree` name, i totally missed that lowercase doesn't matter

Comment: Please, prepare a [mre]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i found the issue. `StringList` from the `TDomTree` was referenced in thread that updated the ui. So therefore, when worker thread tried to destroy the `searchResultTable`, its `TDomTree`'s `StringList` could not be terminated, creating exception, so whole `TDomTree` was not terminating.